# creating multiple dictionary and appending into list using c#

Tags: c#, json, razor-2

I am new to C# and am trying to create something like this using c#. How we can do that any suggestion. I just want to create list of dict.

a = [ { "server": "10.14.13.1", "prefer": "Yes" }, { "server": "10.1.2.1", "prefer": "No" } ]

Comment: Where this is JSON output? What's C# structure that contains this data that you're trying to output? You would typically have your controller return an object and serialize that as JSON, not try to generate JSON from a Razor file - unless this is to be written into an HTML page in a script tag?

Comment: @Rup need in c# to create list of dict. how to do that.

Comment: A list of C# dictionaries? Or objects that will serialize into JSON dictionaries? If it's just JSON dictionaries then I'd suggest using a simple class like David's answer or a value tuple.

Comment: But you can create a C# dictionary using `new Dictionary<string,string>`, or using LINQ's `.ToDictionary`, and then just add those to a list. I don't know of an easy way to create a dictionary from constant values though. Or if you're transforming some other list of dictionaries then that's easy to do with LINQ Select etc. too.

Comment: @Rup this way i do in python: lst = []
for i in some_source:
    dict = {}
    dict["server"] = i.server_ip
    dict["prefer = i.prefer_type
    lst.append(dict)

Comment: @Rup 
    where server and prefer values will come from some_souce(consider excel)
    so i will loop and create dict and append into list
    so at end of loop my list will have multiple dictionary(based on some_source )
    so how can I do it in c#?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class POCO
{
    [JsonProperty("server")]
    public string Server { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prefer")]
    public string Prefer { get; set; }
}

POCO o1 = new POCO("10.1.2.1", "No");
POCO o2 = new POCO("10.1.2.2", "YES");
List<POCO> list = new List<POCO>() {o1, o2};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);  //<-- this is what you want
```

Notes

1. this is code snippet only, and we need constructor(a,b) to make it fully working.
2. You don't have to create the POCO object yourself, there is plenty of online tools, e.g. https://app.quicktype.io/ to help you in this.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229260/unity-json-de-serializing-nested-data/45229840#45229840) also.

[image]

Comment: @David but this is static. I need to create list of dict that dict value comes from another list dict.

Comment: @sonali don't quite follow. What do  you mean by static and how to create a dict  out of another one?

Comment: this way i do in python: lst = [] for i in some_source: dict = {} dict["server"] = i.server_ip dict["prefer = i.prefer_type lst.append(dict)

Comment: where server and prefer values will come from some_souce(consider excel) so i will loop and create dict and append into list so at end of loop my list will have multiple dictionary(based on some_source ) so how can I do it in c#?

Comment: you can use dynamic object, but you lose the strong type of C#! You have your choice, :) !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects