# Create a list of dict using other list of dict data in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I am new to C#. Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

My question is

I have a list of dict in some x variable. My dict look like something like below.

```
x = [
        {
            "name": "rtu_dnp3",
            "ipv4": "10.46.224.109/32",
            "loopback": "yes",
            "sap": "1/3/1",
            "type": "serial"
        },
        {
            "name": "rtu_ea",
            "ipv4": "10.46.224.109/32",
            "loopback": "yes",
            "sap": "1/3/2",
            "type": "serial"
        }
]
```

Using this dictionary I want to create another dictionary. This I do easily in python.

```
y = []
for i in x:
    dict = {}
    dict["name"] = i["name"]
    dict["ipv4"] = i["ipv4"]
    y.append(dict)
```

So can anyone help me how to do in C# Code? So I can play with this dictionaries to create my own format.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794865/creating-multiple-dictionary-and-appending-into-list-using-c-sharp/61795007#61795007

Comment: It seems, that you'll need to deserialize a json into custom dictionary

Comment: It's not clear what you really have here. A JSON string? Or an array of `Dictionary` instances? A `List` of `Dictionary` instances? [Edit] the question and provide a [example] i.e. real and complete C# code that actually compiles.

Comment: this is json data. I am looping through my c# code. but I am not able to create dictionary-like I explain above in c#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating multiple dictionary and appending into list using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794865/creating-multiple-dictionary-and-appending-into-list-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple for your dictionary like,

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>> yourDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>>();
yourDict.Add("rtu_dnp3", new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/1", "serial"));
yourDict.Add("rtu_ea", new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/2", "serial"));
```

Or you can create your model instead of tuple like,

```
Dictionary<string, YourModel> yourDict = new Dictionary<string, YourModel>();
yourDict.Add("rtu_dnp3", new YourModel("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/1", "serial"));
yourDict.Add("rtu_ea", new YourModel("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/2", "serial"));

public class YourModel
{
    public string ipv4 { get; set; }
    public string loopback { get; set; }
    public string sap { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public YourModel(string ipv4, string loopback, string sap, string type)
    {
        this.ipv4 = ipv4;
        this.loopback = loopback;
        this.sap = sap;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

In this scenario string is your **key** and YourModel is your **value**

-
**UPDATE**

Dictionary keeps one TKey and one TValue. So you should use some struct or class (your class or pre-defined classes like Tuple) to keep multiple parameters. Let's contunie with tuple example,

You can copy your dictionary by loop like this,

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>> yourDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>>();
yourDict.Add("rtu_dnp3", new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/1", "serial"));
yourDict.Add("rtu_ea", new Tuple<string, string, string, string>("10.46.224.109/32", "yes", "1/3/2", "serial"));

var newDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string, string>>();

foreach (var item in yourDict)
{
    newDict.Add(item.Key,item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Furkan Öztürk, Can u consider my python code and try to give a simple answer using loop and without using any class. It would be helpfull for me

Comment: I hope this will be helpful. For addition, you should give more detail about your case for us to being helpful @DhananjayaDN

Answer (score 1):

Consider the next `C#` code sample. I think that it is an equivalent of the `Python` code provided by you:

```
var x = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["name"] = "rtu_dnp3",
        ["ipv4"] = "10.46.224.109/32",
        ["loopback"] = "yes",
        ["sap"] = "1/3/1",
        ["type"] = "serial"
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["name"] = "rtu_ea",
        ["ipv4"] = "10.46.224.109/32",
        ["loopback"] = "yes",
        ["sap"] = "1/3/2",
        ["type"] = "serial"
    }
};

var y = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (Dictionary<string, string> i in x)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict["name"] = i["name"];
    dict["ipv4"] = i["ipv4"];
    y.Add(dict);
}
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y6WZtZ) that also prints resulting list of dictionaries `y` to the output window.

Here are links to learn about `C#'s` collections [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1).